# Deploying Django project with FTP

Tags: django, apache, ftp

I just deployed my Django project via FTP, now when I try to run `./manage.py shell` it keeps on saying `ImportError: Could not import settings 'somedjango.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named settings`

Its an ubuntu server.I even updated `httpd.conf` to

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django_venv/mydjango/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/django_venv
<Directory /var/www/django_venv>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Still no luck

Please let me know if I lack any information and I will add that as well

Structure of the app

```
django_venv
--venv
--templates
--mydjango
----settings.py
----wsgi.py
----url.py
--app1
--app2
--requirement.txt
--Procfile
--manage.py
```

## manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mydjango.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Where's your settings module

Comment: Leonardo.Z I updated it in the question

Comment: What's the content of manage.py?

Comment: Is the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in manange.py points to `mydjango.settings`

Comment: Leonardo.Z, I adde dthat in the question as well

Comment: Your local settings file is probably going to vary greatly from your deployed settings file, unless you've created an exact copy of your deployment server locally.  Either way, could you post your settings.py? also, please provide your wsgi.py too

Comment: Was the venv pushed with FTP as well or created on the target system? It's possible that the interpreter path is incorrect in some of the venv's .py files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a last resort, you should try to append absolute paths to your sys.path, inside your wsgi.py file.

```
import sys 
import os

sys.path.append('path/to/mydjango')
# sys.path.append('path/to/mydjango/mydjango')
# more as needed.
```

And then the usual :

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mydjango.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Once you get it up and running, you can start replacing absolute paths with relative ones (or if confident, do so from beginning).

Hope this helps,

Regards,